# Moving background repetitively in window Phone 7.

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation

I am creating a simple animation in windows Phone 7.1 which has following two elements.

1) Background Scene 
2) Actor : Car

I want to show an animation of moving car on a road on drag gesture. I have a background image of 480px*3200px wide and my screen orientation is landscape.

so how I can move the background image repetitively in background on user drag action so it shows the effect of moving car. the car is also using double animation for showing the wheels moving which is triggered while user start the drag action.

could you please guide me with the approach.

Thanks for your time.

SAM

Answer (score 0):

You may use a translate transform:

```
<Image>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransform"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Then you can animate the background with a simple DoubleAnimation:

```
<Storyboard TargetName="TranslateTransform" TargetProperty="X">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-3200" Duration="00:00:05">
</Storyboard>
```

Is this what you need?